# NLP : What is the difference between Authorship Attribution, Authorship Identification and Authorship Recognition?

Tags: nlp

I have to write my Master's thesis on this topic (I'm in Natural Language Processing) and while I sometimes see these terms used interchangeably other sources seem to emphasize the fact that there are distinctions between them without explaining in what they differ.

Comment: I have worked in this field and I'm not sure I can tell the difference myself between these 3. The important question is usually whether the problem is *closed-set*, meaning the author of the unknown text must belong to a set of authors known and fixed at training stage, or *open-set*, where the author might not be known at all. In the past decade the field has progressed in the direction of open-set, which is more challenging but more realistic. In particular there has been a focus on the question of *author verification*: given two texts, are they both written by the same person?